# How to save screenshot to specified directory using xfce4-screenshooter without dialogs?

Tags: screenshot, xfce

`xfce4-screenshooter --help` says that `-s` option is needed to specify saving directory.

But there is a problem: when I run in the console (or using key bind) `xfce4-screenshooter -ws ~/screenshoots`, it opens `Save as...` dialogue instead of just saving to specified directory.

What can I do?

Answer (score 6):

You can try `-o` option:
`mv "$(xfce4-screenshooter -wo ls)" ~/screenshoots`

Comment: Unfortonately this didn't work in XFCE's Application Shortcuts, I had to use for example `sh -c "mv \`xfce4-screenshooter -ro ls\` ~/Screenshots"`